# managing a click on the element of an android tablelayout

Tags: java, android, xml, tablelayout, tablerow

I need to manage a specific time slot as shown in the picture.

[image: week]

I need that when I click on a specific TextView, it opens a new fragment sending me which element was clicked on. That is the layout file

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayoutWeek"
    >
    <!--riga dei giorni-->
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/blueBlack"
        android:padding="20dp"

        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="lun"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="mar"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="mer"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="gio"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="ven"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </TableRow>
    <!--riga delle 16-->
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/yellowRow"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/row16"

        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lun16"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="16:00"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mar16"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="16:00"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:tag="mer16"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="16:00"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:tag="gio16"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="16:00"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:tag="ven16"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="16:00"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
    </TableRow>
    <!--riga delle 17-->
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/yellowRow"
        android:padding="20dp"

        >

        <TextView
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="17:00"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="17:00"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="17:00"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="17:00"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="17:00"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
    </TableRow>
    <!--riga delle 18-->
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/yellowRow"
        android:padding="20dp"

        >

        <TextView
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="18:00"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="18:00"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="18:00"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="18:00"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="18:00"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
    </TableRow>
    <!--riga delle 19-->
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/yellowRow"
        android:padding="20dp"

        >

        <TextView
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="19:00"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="19:00"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="19:00"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="19:00"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="19:00"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            />
    </TableRow>


</TableLayout>
```

I tried this way, but I always get the row id and not the child id.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    binding = FragmentWeekBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    View root = binding.getRoot();
    binding.row16.setClickable(true);
    binding.row16.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int id = view.getId();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "pos:" + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    return root;

}
```

I also tried tag but it still doesn't work, does anyone have any solution to recommend? I would be very grateful

Comment: `need that when I click on a specific time,` ? You mean: `need that when I click on a specific TextView`?,

Comment: Probably you should set an onClick listener on every TextView.

Comment: Most of your TextViews dont have an id.

Answer (score 0):

Set an onClickListener on every TextView.

Example: https://www.folkstalk.com/tech/onclicklistener-and-table-layout-with-example/

It's done on a Button. Change to a TextView.

Comment: it is not possible with databinding to use a single function that will be triggered for each textView, within which to then make a switch via the id?

Comment: Why not? Did you try?

Answer (score 0):

```
// The row the view is in
TableRow row = (TableRow) view.getParent();
// It's index
int index = tableLayout.indexOfChild(row);
```